# Autocomplete with query php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-autocomplete

I have three fields in my form.

For example: `Brand`, `Model`, `Engine`.

When I insert the `Brand`, I'd like the `Model` field to give me the possibility of inserting the `Model` text and a list from a database using autocomplete.

I'm not having a problem building an autocomplete script from a db using `SELECT model FROM cars WHERE brand = 'the_brand_field'`, but I'd like to figure out how to take the `Brand` variable from the previous field.

Can I run the query when the `Model` field receives `focus`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `jQuery`, wait for `Model` field to gain focus and trigger an AJAX call to PHP to load the data for autocomplete. Return back in JSON and parse the data within jQuery and display them.

There are some free autocomplete jQuery plugins, just google and pick one that You'd like.

Usually these plugins work for the concrete input using it's value for searching and autocompletion and triggered after `keydown` or `keyup` events, so You would have to change/modify this behavior slightly... Should be still less work than implementing Your own autocomplete.

Comment: So You suggest to: when Model get focus take with jQuery the value of the Brand field and call thru AJAX (sending the Brand variable got before) the data from a php script. Should works?